# Trying to build a linked-list with strings as its entries

Tags: c, string, pointers, linked-list

I'm trying to create a linked-list with strings as it data, and I have to do some opperations with them, but the opperations are cleared for integers only.

Those are the functions I've done the past weeks:

```
struct node {

  int data;
  char* s;

  struct node* next;

};

typedef struct node node;

int remove_by_data(node** L, int data) {

  if (*L == NULL) {
    return 0;
  }

  node* p = *L;

  if (p->data == data) {
    *L = p->next;
    free(p);
    return 1;
  }
  else {
    while (p->next != NULL && p->next->data != data) {
      p = p->next;
    }

    if (p->next == NULL) {
      return 0;
    }
    else {
      node* q = p->next;
      p->next = p->next->next;
      free(q);
      return 1;
    }
  }
}

node* search(node* L, int data) {

  node* p = L;

  while (p != NULL) {

    if (p->data == data)
      return p;

    p = p->next;
 }

  return NULL;
}

int insert_end(node** L, int data) {

  node* aux = malloc(sizeof(node));
  if (!aux)
    return 0;

  aux->data = data;
  aux->next = NULL;

  node* p = *L;

  if (p == NULL) {
    *L = aux;
  }
  else {
    while (p->next) {
      p = p->next;
    }

    p->next = aux;
  }

  return 1;
}

int insert_begin(node** L, int data) {

  node* aux = malloc(sizeof(node));
  if (!aux)
    return 0;

  aux->data = data;
  aux->next = *L;
  *L = aux;

  return 1;
}

void print_data(node* L) {

  node* p = L;
  while (p != NULL) { // while (p) {
    printf("%d ",p->data);
    p = p->next;
  }
  printf("\n");
}

int cont(node* L, int N){

  int cont=1;
  node* atual= L;

  while (atual != search(L, N)){
    cont++;
    atual = atual->next;
  }
  return cont;
}

void swap_node(node** L, int m, int n){
  int i, t;
  node* p;
  node* q;

  p = q = *L;

  for(i=1; i<m; i++)
    p = p->next;

  for(i=1; i<n; i++)
    q = q->next;

  t = p->data;
  p->data = q->data;
  q->data = t;  

}
```

I just don't know how to "convert" those functions to strings, and how can I store a string into a list

Comment: Pass a string argument to `insert_ begin` and `insert_end`, malloc the string length memory to `s` or use `strdup` to copy the string to structure variable. access the string with `struct_var->s`. When deleting please free the memory allocated for string.

Comment: Can you focus your question on the first of your problems and describe that in more detail? Also, making an [mcve] which shows that single problem would be appreciated.